# Vim plugin failing to load.

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, pathogen

I have a [vim configuration on github](https://github.com/joereddington/dotvimdirectory/) with [a single plugin](https://github.com/freitass/todo.txt-vim) as a submodule.

I set it up in a new user area like so:

```
  561  git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/joereddington/dotvimdirectory/
  562  mv dotvimdirectory/ .vim
  563  ls .vim
  564  $ ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc
  565  ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc
  568  vim todo.txt
```

But the submodule, which is checked out, doesn't give me any mappings:

(results of :map in vim) 
[image]

Despite the fact that the syntax highlighting is working fine:

[image]

Why aren't the plugin mappings loading?

Comment: Can we see your vimrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't turn on filetype plugins in your *.vimrc*:

```
filetype plugin on
```

This is used by your plugin. Check `:h ftplugin` and `:h add-filetype-plugin`.

Comment: Very frustrating that the syntax part of the plugin is a seperate part.  Thank you.